# generate mutiple tab table via for loop in shiny

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny

My real data generate mutiple tables in a loop, and I would like to show them all in shiny.

When I am testing fake data, I am not able to generate a multiple tab table via for loop, here is my code:

```
library(shiny)

df1<-data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5,nrow = 10,data = runif(50,0,100),dimnames = list(1:10,paste0("S",1:5))))

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("S1",tableOutput("S1")),
            tabPanel("S2",tableOutput("S2")),
            tabPanel("S3",tableOutput("S3")),
            tabPanel("S4",tableOutput("S4")),
            tabPanel("S5",tableOutput("S5"))
        )
        ),
    
    ##not working here
    fluidRow(
        tabsetPanel(
            for(i in 1:ncol(df1)){
                tabPanel(title = paste0("S",i),tableOutput(outputId = paste0("test_S",i)))
            }
            )
        )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$S1<-renderTable(df1[1])
    output$S2<-renderTable(df1[2])
    output$S3<-renderTable(df1[3])
    output$S4<-renderTable(df1[4])
    output$S5<-renderTable(df1[5])
    
    
    ##not woking here
    for(i in 1:ncol(df1)){
        id<-paste0("test_S",i)
        output[[id]]<-renderTable(df1[i])
    }
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

The code generate noting in the for loop part, how do I revise the for loop part to generate the same result as my above table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using `lapply` to create your dynamic content in `server` and not `ui`. This will include `renderUI` to create the dynamic number of tabs based on your data.frame (number of columns), and an `observe` to dynamically create the `renderTable` outputs. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
library(shiny)

set.seed(42)

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 10, data = runif(50, 0, 100),
                         dimnames = list(1:10, paste0("S", 1:5))))

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("mytabs")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$mytabs <- renderUI({
    thetabs <- lapply(paste0('table_', seq_len(ncol(df1))),
                      function(x) {
                        tabPanel(x, tableOutput(x))
                      })
    do.call(tabsetPanel, thetabs)
  })
  
  observe({
    lapply(seq_len(ncol(df1)), function(x) {
      output[[paste0("table_", x)]] <- renderTable({ df1[x] })
    })
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I would like to do, I am trying my best to undestand it!